# Tutorial to implement push notifications in iOS 6 with Google Compute Engine

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, push-notification, endpoint

While PAAS solution (either by Amazon, Google even Heroku) offer endpoints for mobile devices making the process of push notification easier, this is not the case with IAAS. I'm looking for a good step by step tutorial on how to make it with iOS & Google Compute Engine.

Please point to a good tutorial, or share some code or GitHub project.

Comment: This was rather brief for a Stack Overflow question back in 2013, and these days is regarded as off-topic, since it is a request for tutorials/code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little more detailed than the one provided by Google:

[iOS push notification with google app engine](http://mcneish1.rssing.com/chan-12494922/all_p3.html)